golang sending email with azure communication service
I have an azure communication service template for sending email.
Our project is in golang and i need to implement a method to send email based on azure communication service.
I found karim-w library but not worked for me and it's complicated.
I implemented this code in python and it's working correctly.
I wanna implement this in golang too.
Any idea or suggestion?


from azure.communication.email import EmailClient
def main():
    try:
        connection_string = "endpoint=https://announcement.unitedstates.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=***********"
        client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        message = {
            "senderAddress": "DoNotReply@domain.com",
            "recipients":  {
                "to": [{"address": "example@gmail.com" }],
            },
            "content": {
                "subject": "Test Email",
                "plainText": "Hello world via email.",
            }
        }
        poller = client.begin_send(message)
        result = poller.result()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
main()



Thanks in advance

There's email functionality in an unofficial SDK. Credit to Karim. You can try something like this:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/Karim-W/go-azure-communication-services/emails"
)

func main() {
    connectionString := "endpoint=https://announcement.unitedstates.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=***********"

    // Parse connection string
    endpoint, accessKey := parseConnectionString(connectionString)

    // Create new client
    client := emails.NewClient(
        endpoint,
        accessKey,
        nil, // version (uses defaultAPIVersion)
    )

    // Prepare payload
    payload := emails.Payload{
        Headers: emails.Headers{
            ClientCorrelationID:    "some-correlation-id",
            ClientCustomHeaderName: "some-custom-header",
        },
        SenderAddress: "sender@example.com",
        Content: emails.Content{
            Subject:   "Test Email",
            PlainText: "This is a test email.",
            HTML:      "<p>This is a <strong>test</strong> email.</p>",
        },
        Recipients: emails.Recipients{
            To: []emails.ReplyTo{
                {
                    Address:     "recipient@example.com",
                    DisplayName: "Recipient Name",
                },
            },
        },
        UserEngagementTrackingDisabled: false,
    }

    // Send email
    ctx := context.Background()
    result, err := client.SendEmail(ctx, payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending email:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Email sent successfully:", result)
}

// parseConnectionString parses the connection string to extract endpoint and access key
func parseConnectionString(connStr string) (string, string) {
    parts := strings.Split(connStr, ";")
    var endpoint, accessKey string
    for _, part := range parts {
        if strings.HasPrefix(part, "endpoint=") {
            endpoint = strings.TrimPrefix(part, "endpoint=")
        }
        if strings.HasPrefix(part, "accesskey=") {
            accessKey = strings.TrimPrefix(part, "accesskey=")
        }
    }
    return endpoint, accessKey
}

Make sure to replace "***********" with your actual access key and adjust the payload according to your requirements. This code assumes that the access key is provided in plain text in the connection string for simplicity. In a real-world scenario, you'd want to handle the access key securely, possibly using environment variables or secret management tools.
This example assumes you will retain the existing connection string format.

Thanks. I run your code and i could install required sdk for second import. but i get this error for first import :    github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/communication/email: module github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@latest found (v68.0.0+incompatible), but does not contain package github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/communication/email          this can't find any sdk for email ... could you please send me the exact url or comments for install azure sdk step by step?

I run this command go get -u -d github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/...   but it installed just the second import dependencies. the first import dependency is not actioned yet

could you please tell me how install required sdk? i can't run your code @architect-jamie

@Bahar_Engineer Can you try this? go get -u -d github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/communication/email/...

I tried and I got the same error. There is no such package called communication/email, @ArchitectJamie where does it come from? Does it have a GoDoc link?

Sorry I mixed up tech stacks. There's an unofficial sdk you can use. I've updated my answer. Hope this helps.

I can't comment on the above-accepted answer; hence, I am providing another answer.
Please note a few changes for the sample code to work in 2024.

connection string:

remove https:// as it is appended by the library.
remove the leading / at the end of the communication-server. It leads to the wrong auth header and results in 401.



example:

connectionString := "endpoint=demo-communication-server.unitedstates.communication.azure.com;accesskey=your-access-key"


The Azure rest API requires attachments to be passed in even though you have no attachments. here is the updated payload that works.

payload: = emails.Payload {
  Headers: emails.Headers {
    ClientCorrelationID: "some-correlation-id",
    ClientCustomHeaderName: "some-custom-header",
  },
  SenderAddress: "<DoNotReply@b64896f1-9811-4127-a0cb-ff6eed9c186d.azurecomm.net>",
  Content: emails.Content {
    Subject: "Fabric tenant abcde wants to upgrade to paid offer",
    PlainText: "This is being generated from dev-server.",
    HTML: "<p>This is a <strong>test</strong> email.</p>",
  },
  Recipients: emails.Recipients {
    To: [] emails.ReplyTo {
      {
        Address: "fabric_war_room-aaaamrshwczhmuu3o4yd7k6eje@teradata.slack.com",
        DisplayName: "Garima Bathla",
      },
    },
  },
  Attachments: [] emails.Attachment {},
  UserEngagementTrackingDisabled: false,
}


The sender's email address needs to be in this format:

SenderAddress: "<DoNotReply@4127-a0cb-ff6eed9c186d.azurecomm.net>",

